# access other computer's localhost on home network

Tags: localhost, google-chrome-os, reverse-proxy

I have a Chromebook with a Debian chroot command-line environment installed. From Debian, I run a http server (similar to Python's SimpleHTTPServer), and it works perfectly when I navigate to `localhost:8000` or `192.168.1.67:8000` from within Chrome OS (i.e. the same physical device).

How can I view these same pages with my phone or other devices on my home network?

What I tried:

- simply navigating to 192.168.1.67:8000 from my phone
- simply navigating to 192.168.1.67 (no port number) from my phone
- messing with the proxy settings from within Chrome OS
- adjusting router settings (it would not let me)

So far all I see on my phone is a "not found" error.

Ideally I could tweak some setting from within Debian or install a program (Nginx? Squid? I don't know where to start) to allow devices in my home network to access what's currently going to localhost.

Comment: It might be the case that you need to specify in the webserver's configuration file what address(es) to listen on. Make sure it's set to listen on either "all" addresses, or that it includes 192.168.1.67.  That should at least ensure that you're able to access it from the home network.

Comment: @0xDAFACADE, if he can access it using his LAN IP (`192.168.1.67`) then it is most likely already bound to that IP.  I would guess that perhaps a firewall is blocking external connections.  Also, does your phone have a `192.168.1.X` IP address as well?

Comment: @heavyd Yep, my phone has a 192.168.1.x address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found both an explanation as to why this didn't immediately work, and what to do to fix it [here](http://www.overdigital.com/2013/06/02/how-to-use-your-chromebook-pixel-as-a-webserver/).

The magical missing step was to open that port *before* entering the chroot:

`sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

And then enter the chroot as normal, fire up the webserver, and navigate to it with the phone. Yay my site looks terrible!